# Sending image file and data in one post request

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios

I'm trying to send image file and data in one post request with `axios`:

```
 const fd = new FormData();
 fd.append("image", selectedFile, selectedFile.name);
 let data = {
      category: category,
      title: title,
      post: text,
      image: fd
    };
    //console.log(fd);
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    };
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/blog/posts";
    axios
      .post(url, fd, headers)
      .then(resp => { ...
```

Flask back-end:

```
    image = request.files['image']
    category = request.files['category']
    title = request.files['title']
    post = request.files['post']
```

log output:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'category'
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Add the data as entries to the FormData object and send it. As an example: ```formData.append("category", category);``` Use ```request.form``` in your route for all entries that do not represent a file. As an example: ```category = request.form['category']``` Possibly use ```.get(key, ...)``` to bypass the ```KeyError``` and get ```None``` if the data is not available or to pass a default value.

Comment: @Detlef  It worked ! Feel free to submit it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad to have helped you. Should have put it straight away as an answer. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a FormData object which is transmitted as "multipart/formdata". In other words, in multiple parts of data that are transmitted in individual sections of a broadcast.

Use the `FormData` object for all data that you want to transfer. Add the data as entries to the `FormData` object.

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append ("image", selectedFile, selectedFile.name);
fd.append("category", category);
// ...
```

The different types of data and files can be reached within the route in a different way from the `request` object.
Use `request.form` in your route for all entries that do not represent a file.

```
image = request.files['image']
category = request.form['category']
# ...
```

Possibly use `.get(key[, ...])` to bypass the `KeyError` and get `None` if the data is not available or to pass a default value.

```
category = request.form.get('category', 'Uncategorized')
```

Comment: "Possibly use .get(key[, ...]) to bypass the KeyError and get None if the data is not available or to pass a default value."  in my case that's not necessary because I'm not allowing user to submit the form with empty fields. One can either handle it on the back end or on the front end. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You create a `data` object, but don't seem to do anything with it. If you're using `FormData`, you should append all your data points to it. So your code should look something like this:

```
const fd = new FormData();
fd.append("image", selectedFile, selectedFile.name);
fd.append("category", category);
fd.append("title", title);
...
```

Then you can just post it the way you post it:

```
axios
      .post(url, fd, headers)
      .then(resp => { ...
```